# Jboss EAP 7 Issue after Restarting

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I ran into Issue after restarting the jboss EAP 7 ,I am unable to access it through its public interface but I'm able to connect to admin console.I have restated the server but no luck

Comment: How are you restarting JBoss EAP?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I have restarted through ADMIN Console and Command Line Both

Comment: Odd it seems to work for me. I was just starting with `-b 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: i have been using the same command and it works perfectly with the exception of last time, I end up reinstalling the jboss server just want to know was reinstalling the only solution ?